# Need helpwith YellowPages spider

Tags: scrapy, yellow-pages

I'm new to scrapy, I've been able to create a few spiders so far. I would like to write a spider that will crawl Yellowpages, looking for websites that have a 404 response, the spider is working OK, however, the pagination is not working. Any help will be much appreciated. thanks in advance

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    #allowed_domains = ['www.yellowpages.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=handyman&geo_location_terms=Miami%2C+FL']

    def parse(self, response):
    for listing in response.css('div.search-results.organic div.srp-listing'):

        url = listing.css('a.track-visit-website::attr(href)').extract_first()

        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)


    # follow pagination links

    next_page_url = response.css('a.next.ajax-page::attr(href)').extract_first()
    next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
    if next_page_url:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_details(self,response):
    yield{'Response': response,}
```

Comment: Hi David, this is my first time posting here and I was having problems formatting the code. my question is very simple I'm having issues with the pagination of this spider.And not sure what am I missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and found out that there are some errors. In the **first loop**, you don't check the value of `url` and sometimes it is `None`. This error stops the execution, that's why you thought the pagination didn't work.

Here is a working code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    #allowed_domains = ['www.yellowpages.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=handyman&geo_location_terms=Miami%2C+FL']

    def parse(self, response):
        for listing in response.css('div.search-results.organic div.srp-listing'):
            url = listing.css('a.track-visit-website::attr(href)').extract_first()
            if url:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)
        next_page_url = response.css('a.next.ajax-page::attr(href)').extract_first()
        next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_details(self,response):
        yield{'Response': response,}
```

Comment: No problem, if this solved your problem don't hesitate to validate the answer.